# Intent type for any file.

Tags: android, android-intent

Which intent type may i use to pick any file, but just files?
For example, i don't want to share selected text through my app.

At the moment, my intent filter looks like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Picking a file and sharing a file or sharing something are two things. So where is your question about?

Comment: I think, the appropriate title of this question is Mime Type, instead of Intent type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<data android:mimeType="application/*" />
<data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
<data android:mimeType="video/*" />
```

Do not use:

```
<data android:mimeType="text/*" />
<data android:mimeType="message/*" />
```